# How can I automate builds and deployments with ASP.Net WebForms?

Tags: webforms, build-automation

I have a web application created with ASP.Net WebForms and I would like to know some alternatives to automatize the builds and releases in live version without manual steps (as much as possible):

- merge from test branch to main branch (TFS on-promise)
- assembly info update (increase version number)
- package creation
- copy and paste files to live server
- update the physical path of web site in IIS
- notification emails with result